# Calculating a BigDecimal results in inaccurate answer

Tags: java, math

So I just wanted to screw around to see if I can make it so I can calculate E, but instead have it so I can have dynamic degrees of precision. While I did technically accomplish it, no matter what int i put in for the variable PRECISION, the last few numbers are always different from what the actual value of E is suppose to be. I'm not entirely sure why, but help would be appreciated.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal; //To use for calculating E

public class ComputeE {
    public static double calcDenominator(int n)
    {
        double denominator = 1.0;   //Start the BigInt with 1
        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) // Run n-1 amount of times
        {
            denominator = denominator * i;   // Multiply BigInteger by the BigInteger obtained with the int value i
        }
        return denominator;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        BigDecimal e = new BigDecimal(0.0);
        int PRECISION = 15;
        int iterations = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < PRECISION; i++)
        {
            iterations++;
            BigDecimal numerator = new BigDecimal(1.0); // to divide, we need two BigDecimals, the numerator is 1
            BigDecimal factorial = new BigDecimal(calcDenominator(i));  // the denominator is i! which we get from calling the factorial method
            factorial = numerator.divide(factorial, PRECISION, BigDecimal.ROUND_UNNECESSARY);  // compute 1/i!, note divide is overloaded, this version is used to
                                                                  //     ensure a limit to the iterations when division is limitless like 1/3
            e = e.add(factorial);                   // add the latest 1/i! to e

        }



        System.out.println("Computed value of e : " + e);
        System.out.println("Expected value of e : " + Math.E);

    }
}
```

Comment: Because e is irrational, which literally means that no two integers of any finite size can be divided to make it?

Comment: @NathanHughes Could you clarify what you mean by that, I'm not familiar with your terminology.

Comment: Since Euler's number is irrational, it means you can't recreate it with a fraction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Rounding *is* necessary here.  Use something like `HALF_EVEN`.  Even better, use the enum value `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN`, because the integer constants for rounding mode are deprecated.
2. In `calcDenominator`, change your `for` loop condition to `i <= n`, or else you'll add `1` one too many times in `main` and you'll get a value that's `1` too high.
3. You can use `BigDecimal.ONE` to initialize `numerator`.  This doesn't affect the result, but why create an unnecessary object?  Same comment on the initialization of `e`, except with `BigDecimal.ZERO`.
4. You are using the first `PRECISION` terms of an infinite series (Maclaurin Series) that approximates *e*, an irrational number.  There is an error term when you cut off the `for` loop, and that is expected mathematically.  With the above changes, and bumping `PRECISION` to `50`, I get the following, which looks sufficiently precise.

```
Computed value of e : 2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775496954201584
Expected value of e : 2.718281828459045
```

It is precise, despite using the `double` constructor for `BigDecimal` because the significant digits for a `double` start with the first non-zero bit, so even if you're calculating 1/n! for large `n`, the significant digits are good enough for adding to the existing approximation for *e*.